# count() vs length in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

According to the documentation, there are 2 ways to get how many elements are inside the `ElementArrayFinder` (the result of `element.all()` call):

- `$$(".myclass").length`, documented [here](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder):

> ...the array has `length` equal to the `length` of the elements found by the `ElementArrayFinder` and each result represents the result of performing the action on the element.

- `$$(".myclass").count()`, documented [here](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count):

> Count the number of elements represented by the `ElementArrayFinder`.

What is the difference between these two methods and which one should be preferred?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

---

### `$$(".myclass").length`

Need to resolve the promise to get the length of element correctly.

```js
// WORK
$$(".myclass").then(function(items){
  items.length;
});

// DOES NOT WORK
$$(".myclass").length;
```

---

### `$$(".myclass").count()`

A wrapper for `$$('.myclass').length` which being a promise itself and doesn't require to resolve promise like `.length`

```
$$(".myclass").count();
```

---

> which one should be preferred?

Unless there some complex business when locating `$$(".myclass")` and `.then(function(items){...})` involved then `items.length` will give better performance.

Otherwise `$$(".myclass").count()` should always be used.

Comment: length is not listed as a method on ElementArrayFinder. It's in the description and the example, but not in the method-list... Count returns a promise. I guess they changed that. But why is length still available on ElementArrayFinder?